# Which would be more effective

Tags: bodybuilding, muscle-gain

I work with high intensity low volume technique. That means doing only 2 sets in most exercises, but going to failure on every set, generally aiming to fail between 6 and 8 reps. Now and then, I'm not certain what weight I need to fail around 6 reps and will find myself already at the 6-8 rep range, but feeling like I'm only half way to failure. When this happens I contemplate whether I should continue on to failure at 12+ reps or stop, conserving energy, allowing me to go heavier on the next set. Most often, I end up continuing on to failure, then using the same weight for the next set with the reasoning that both sets to failure are better than 1 even it would've allowed me to go heavier. I train with the main objective of gaining strength. I prioritise strength increase over hypertrophy and bodybuilding goals and so for that purpose, which option would be more effective to reach that goal?

Comment: More effective *for what*? We need something to optimize for.

Answer (score 1):

If the only options are:

1. stopping one set with 6 reps left in reserve, then doing a second heavier set to failure at a 6-8RM load, or
2. Continuing the first left to failure, and then doing a second set to failure at a slightly lighter weight than a true 6-8RM load.

Option 2 is probably more effective a training stimulus, as you're doing two hard sets rather than one easy set and one hard set. Another option, more time consuming but almost certainly more effective for strength development, would be to stop the first set when you realise it's too light, treat it as a warm-up set, and then adjust the weight and do your originally intended 2 sets at a higher adjusted weight.

However, this definitely shouldn't be happening so often that it has any measurable effect on your overall training outcomes. How are you so unfamiliar with how much weight you can lift that you aren't able to select the correct weight for a desired 6-8RM load? If it's because you're constantly changing exercises, then the solution would be to stop that and train with more regular exercise selection so that you can better measure your progress.